# Fast Fourier Transform using numpy

Tags: fft, mfcc, numpy

I am a computer science student and didn't really have signal processing as a subject. Maybe I should be clear on the concepts of sampling rate and frequency of the signal but I am a little confused.
I was trying to code and understand the process of finding MFCC filter banks on audio files. One intermediate step is to find FFT. I computed and plot the fft results of my audio but wasn`t sure that I was doing things correct as I didnt know the component frequencies that may have been present on my audio.

So I decided to form a sample wave and find and plot the fft results of the test signal.(The np.fft.fftfreq functions return the frequencies corresponding to the fft computed by np.fft.fft()).So my questions are

1) I found out value of y for time at a separation of 1ms seconds( 0 to 1, 1000 values). So my sampling rate should be 1000 right?. Then according to the np.fft.fftfreq() function, the second parameter should be 1/sampling rate. Then it gives correct values for 1/1000. However if I give sampling rate as 100(T=1/100) and give the second parameter as 1/100. It gives wrong results. Why??

2) If I give the frequency of the sine wave as 1080 instead of 80 for T=1/1000. Then also it gives same results as for 80. Why is it so?

```
# EXAMPLE SIGNAL TAKEN TO VERIFY ABOVE FFT PROCEDURE IS RIGHT
NUM=1000
T=1/1000
tt=np.linspace(0,NUM*T,num=NUM)
#So I take readings every T seconds = 1ms

print(1/T)
y=np.sin(2*np.pi*1080*tt)#+np.sin(2*np.pi*90*tt)
#plt.plot(tt,y)
NFFT=1024
mag_frames = np.absolute(np.fft.rfft(y, NFFT))
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), NUM/2)
freq=np.fft.rfftfreq(NFFT,1/1000)
plt.plot(freq,mag_frames)
```

3) What should be value for the second parameter when I perform fft on a audio data imported from a .wav file by librosa library with sampling rate = **rate**

I am sorry if the problem is very simple or basic. I am really a beginner in this area, and could not get much help from results in Google search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answers to Your Questions

1. You are right that your time instants are spaced at an interval of $T$. Hence, the *sampling rate* is $1/T$. ($T$ is defined in line 3 of your code.) You are also right that the second parameter of `np.fft.fftfreq()` is the sampling interval $T$. I am, however, not sure why you get wrong results when setting $T=100\,\text{Hz}$.
2. This phenomenon is called [*aliasing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). Nyquist's [*sampling theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) states that frequencies below $f_\text{s}/2=\frac{1}{2T}$ can be captured correctly by the sampling process. Frequencies above half of the sampling frequency are mirrored back to frequencies below half of the frequency. Therefore, a frequency of $1080\text{Hz}$ is too high to be captured correctly.
3. The choice for the second parameter of the FFT, the *FFT length*, depends on the specific application. You have to experiment what leads to the best results. Still, your choice of `NFFT = 1024` is typically a good start.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats exactly what I wanted to know.